# Elasticsearch match complete array of terms

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I need to match a complete array of terms with elasticsearch.
Only documents that have a array with the same elements should be returned.
There should be neither more elements nor a subset of elements in the document's array.
The order of elements does not matter.

Example:

```
 filter:
   id: ["a", "b"]

 documents:  
   id: ["a", "b"] -> match  
   id: ["b", "a"] -> match  
   id: ["a"] -> no match  
   id: ["a", "b", "c"] -> no match
```

Eventually I want to use Java High Level REST Client to implement the query, though a example for elasticsearch dsl will do as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this does not seem to be supported natively you could go ahead and use a script filter to achieve this behavior like so:

```
GET your_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "script": {
            "script": "doc['tags'].values.length == 2"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "tags": {
              "value": "a"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "tags": {
              "value": "b"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The script filter limits the search result by the array size while the term filters specify the values of that array. Make sure to enable [fielddata](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.5/fielddata.html) on the tags **field** in order to execute scripts on it.

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to propose something that will prevent you from maintaining a long chain of "must" conditions as soon as your requirements will change (e.g., imagine you have an array of six items to match). I'm going to rely on a script query, which might look like over-engineered but it will be easy to create a search template out of it (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.5/search-template.html).

```
{
"query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "script": {
          "script": {
            "source": """
              def ids = new ArrayList(doc['id.keyword']);
              def param = new ArrayList(params.terms);
              def isSameSize = ids.size() == param.size();
              def isSameContent = ids.containsAll(param);
              return isSameSize && isSameContent
            """,
            "lang": "painless",
            "params": {
              "terms": [ "a", "b" ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This way, the only thing that you will need to change is the value of the `terms` parameter.